# Attempting to change URL suffixes

Tags: r, url

I want to change a URL suffix to `.com` unless the existing suffix is `.net`, `.co`, `.org`, `.news`, or `.tv`. The function that I'm using changes *all* URL suffixes to `.com`. How should I modify it?

```
modify_suffix <- function(url) {
  suffix <- str_extract(url, "\\.\\w+$")
  if (!suffix %in% c(".net", ".co", ".org", ".news", ".tv")) {
    url <- str_replace(url, "\\.\\w+$", ".com")
  }
  return(url)
}
domo_data$domain <- sapply(domo_data$domain, modify_suffix)
```

Comment: The approach of changing only the characters after the last period isn't generally applicable, since there are some suffixes which themselves contain periods - ".co.uk" and ".org.uk" are two very common examples.

Comment: Your function seems to work as intended (try `sapply(c("test.net", "test.fr", "test.news"), modify_suffix)`), maybe the content `domo_data$domain` is not what you had in mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few subtleties and gotchas in replacing the suffix using regex (some common suffixes can themselves contain periods, for example).

There are tools already available that can do the job reliably and quickly. For example, if you install the `urltools` package, you can do

```r
urls <- c('https://www.example.com',
          'https://www.example.co.uk',
          'https://www.example.net')

urls <- urltools::suffix_extract(urls)

urls
#>                        host   subdomain  domain suffix
#> 1   https://www.example.com https://www example    com
#> 2 https://www.example.co.uk https://www example  co.uk
#> 3   https://www.example.net https://www example    net
```

This then makes changing suffixes easy and reliable:

```r
urls$suffix[!urls$suffix %in% c("net", "co", "org", "news", "tv")] <- 'com'
urls <- with(urls, paste(subdomain, domain, suffix, sep = '.'))
             
urls
#> [1] "https://www.example.com" "https://www.example.com"
#> [3] "https://www.example.net"
```